# Optimize function in r

Tags: r, optimization, simulation

Here is my code:

```
cee = abs(qnorm(.5*0.1)) # Bonferroni threshold for achieving study-wide significance = 0.1
p.value = (simAll %>% select("p.value"))
p.value1 <- as.numeric(unlist(p.value))
# we use "cee" so R does not get confused with the function 'c'
betahat = log(OR) # Reported OR  
z = sign(betahat)*abs(qnorm(0.5*p.value1)) # Reported p-value = 5.7e-4, which we convert to a z-value

###################################################
#              THE PROPOSED APPROACH              #
###################################################

se = betahat/z # standard error of betahat

mutilde1 = optimize(f=conditional.like,c(-20,20),maximum=T,z=z,cee=cee)$maximum # the conditional mle
```

The p.value is the p-values for 1000 simulations, same as OR, for the "se“ part, I can get 1000 different se values there. But for the mutilde1 line, there is an error exist: "Error in optimize(f = conditional.like, c(-20, 20), maximum = T, z = z,  :
invalid function value in 'optimize'"
How can I fix the issue?
The `conditional.like()` function:

```
conditional.like=function(mu,cee,z){
  like=dnorm(z-mu)/(pnorm(mu-cee)+pnorm(-cee-mu))
  return((abs(z)>cee)*like) }
```

The simALL is a table looks like this (total 1000 lines)：

```
# A tibble: 1,000 x 6
      id term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <int> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1 .x     0.226       0.127    1.78   0.0747  
 2     2 .x     0.137       0.127    1.08   0.280   
 3     3 .x     0.304       0.127    2.38   0.0171  
 4     4 .x     0.497       0.128    3.87   0.000111
```

OR (total 1000 lines):

```
> OR
   [1] 1.5537098 1.0939850 1.4491432 1.6377551 1.1646904 1.3387534 1.6377551 1.5009351 1.7918552
```

Also, here is my overall code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
# create a tibble with an id column for each simulation and x wrapped in list()
sim <- tibble(id = 1:1000,
              x = list(rbinom(1000,1,0.5))) %>% 
  # to generate z, pr, y, k use map and map2 from the purrr package to loop over the list column x
  # `~ ... ` is similar to `function(.x) {...}`
  # `.x` represents the variable you are using map on
  mutate(z  = map(x, ~ log(1.3) * .x), 
         pr = map(z, ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-.x))),
         y  = map(pr, ~ rbinom(1000, 1, .x)),
         k  = map2(x, y, ~ glm(.y ~ .x, family="binomial")),
         # use broom::tidy to get the model summary in form of a tibble
         sum = map(k, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  # select id and sum and unnest the tibbles
  select(id, sum) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(sum))
simOR <- sim %>%
  # drop the intercepts and every .x with a p < 0.05
  filter(term !="(Intercept)",
         p.value < 0.05)

sim
j1=exp(simOR %>% select("estimate"))
OR1=as.numeric(unlist(j1))
mean(OR1)

simAll <- sim %>% 
  filter(term !="(Intercept)")


j <- exp(simAll %>% select("estimate"))
OR2 <- as.numeric(unlist(j))
mean(OR2)

simOR2 <- sim %>%
  filter(term !="(Intercept)",
         p.value < 0.005)

j2 <- exp(simOR2 %>% select("estimate"))
OR3 <- as.numeric(unlist(j2))
mean(OR3)
#op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
hga=hist(OR2, main = NULL, freq = T, breaks = 10) #OR2:Overall OR
hgb=hist(OR1, freq = T,col=2,breaks=10, main="OR:p-value<0.05") #OR1:p-value<0.05
hgc=hist(OR3, freq = T,col=2,breaks=10, main="OR:p-value<0.005") #OR3:p-value<0.005
plot(hga,col=rgb(0,1,0,0.5),main = "OR",xlim=c(0.8,2),ylim=c(0,250))
plot(hgb, add = TRUE,col=rgb(0,0,0.8,0.5),xlim=c(0.8,2),ylim=c(0,250))
plot(hgc, add = TRUE,col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5),xlim=c(0.8,2))
abline(v = mean(OR2), lwd = 4, col = 3)
abline(v = mean(OR3), lwd = 4, col=2)
text(1.65,240,"1.31",col=1)
arrows(1.5,240,1.31,240,length=0.1,col=1,lwd=2)
abline(v = mean(OR1), lwd = 4, col=4)
text(2.1,220,"1.43",col=4)
arrows(1.98,220,1.43,220,length=0.1,col=4,lwd=2)
text(2.1,220,"1.55",col=2)
arrows(1.98,220,1.55,220,length=0.1,col=2,lwd=2)

#########################################
## THE FUNCTIONS BELOW ARE USED TO OBTAIN THE 
## BIAS-CORRECTED ESTIMATES 
#########################################

conditional.like=function(mu,cee,z){
  like=dnorm(z-mu)/(pnorm(mu-cee)+pnorm(-cee-mu))
  return((abs(z)>cee)*like) }

conditional.like.z=function(mu,cee,z){
  return(conditional.like(mu,cee,z)*mu)
}

#########################################
## THE FUNCTIONS BELOW ARE USED TO OBTAIN THE 
## BIAS-CORRECTED CONFIDENCE INTERVAL 
#########################################

ptruncnorm.lower=function(z,mu,cee,alpha){
  A=pnorm(-cee+mu)+pnorm(-cee-mu)
  term1=pnorm(z-mu)
  term2=pnorm(-cee-mu)
  term3=pnorm(-cee-mu)+pnorm(z-mu)-pnorm(cee-mu)
  result=(1/A)*(term1*(z<= -cee)+term2*(abs(z)<cee)+term3*(z>=cee))
  return(result-(alpha/2))
}
ptruncnorm.upper=function(z,mu,cee,alpha){
  A=pnorm(-cee+mu)+pnorm(-cee-mu)
  term1=pnorm(z-mu)
  term2=pnorm(-cee-mu)
  term3=pnorm(-cee-mu)+pnorm(z-mu)-pnorm(cee-mu)
  result=(1/A)*(term1*(z<= -cee)+term2*(abs(z)<cee)+term3*(z>=cee))
  return(result-(1-alpha/2))
}
find.lowerz=function(mu,z,cee,alpha){
  lowerz=uniroot(ptruncnorm.lower,lower=-20,upper=20,mu=mu,cee=cee,alpha=alpha)$root
  return(lowerz-z)
}

find.upperz=function(mu,z,cee,alpha){
  upperz=uniroot(ptruncnorm.upper,lower=-20,upper=20,mu=mu,cee=cee,alpha=alpha)$root
  return(upperz-z)
}

getCI=function(z,cee,alpha){
  uppermu=uniroot(find.lowerz,interval=c(-15,15),cee=cee,z=z,alpha=alpha)$root
  lowermu=uniroot(find.upperz,interval=c(-15,15),cee=cee,z=z,alpha=alpha)$root
  out=list(lowermu,uppermu)
  names(out)=c("lowermu","uppermu")
  return(out)
}
source("GW-functions.R")# YOU READ IN THE FUNCTIONS FOR OUR METHOD
cee=abs(qnorm(.5*0.1)) # Bonferroni threshold for achieving study-wide significance = 0.1
p.value=(simAll %>% select("p.value"))
p.value1 <- as.numeric(unlist(p.value))
# we use "cee" so R does not get confused with the function 'c'
betahat=log(OR) # Reported OR  
z=sign(betahat)*abs(qnorm(0.5*p.value1)) # Reported p-value = 5.7e-4, which we convert to a z-value

###################################################
#              THE PROPOSED APPROACH              #
###################################################

se=betahat/z # standard error of betahat

mutilde1=optimize(f=conditional.like,c(-20,20),maximum=T,z=z,cee=cee)$maximum
```

Comment: Hi Misaya. What is `conditional.like`? This seems to be causing the problem, but you haven't included it in your code here, so it's not possible to debug for you. You also havrn't included `simAll` or `OR`. If we don't know what these are, and you haven't told us, what is it you'd like us to help with?

Comment: @misayali; can you edit your question to add the additional details please

Comment: @user20650 Yes! I just did it!

Comment: @AllanCameron Hello! Thanks for your help! I just edit my question!

Comment: @misayali In `optimize`, the `f()` should be with single value output, but the `conditional.like()` seems to return an array. And are you trying to estimate bias corrected odds ratio by conditional likelihood in `conditional.like()`? It would be helpful for double checking the code if you could elaborate on this approach.

Comment: @RyanSYKwan You are right! I found that the optimize function can only cause a single output. Since I have 1000 z-value, I am considering if I can use a loop function for each of the Z, then the optimize function will work.